Cumulative sum by index, range limited with a single value from a table
I calculate cumulative sum using the following code and it works just fine:
CumulativeSum =
VAR CurrentIndex = 140304
VAR RunningTotal=
CALCULATE(
    SUM(FactTable[ColumnA]),
    FILTER(ALLSELECTED(DimIndex),
    DimIndex[IndexKey] <= MAX (DimIndex[IndexKey])
    )
)
RETURN
IF (
    MAX(DimIndex[IndexKey]) <= CurrentIndex, RunningTotal, BLANK()
)

(results produced by this measure for Indexes greater than or equal to CurrentIndex are replaced by blank)
Here is the result (DarkBlue is non-cumulative values that come from another measure):

I have a table with a single column and a single row in the data model that stores CurrentIndex. when I try to get "140303" from this table using the following dax measure, the visual changes and does not show the desired result:
CumulativeSum =
VAR CurrentIndex = MAX(IndexTable[CurrentIndex])
VAR RunningTotal=
CALCULATE(
    SUM(FactTable[ColumnA]),
    FILTER(ALLSELECTED(DimIndex),
    DimIndex[IndexKey] <= MAX (DimIndex[IndexKey])
    )
)
RETURN
IF (
    MAX(DimIndex[IndexKey]) <= CurrentIndex, RunningTotal, BLANK()
)

Here is the result:

How can I get the value of the CurrentIndex from the table in the data model and yet produce the Previous visual?

Check to see if there are any relationships added on IndexTable.

By adding a simple ALL to the DAX Measure, I fixed the context for CurrentIndex and the problem was solved.
